# Fade to Black Effect in Video Sequence editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is it possible to get fade to black effect (just like in Windows Movie Maker) in the Video Sequence editor?
If so, how?

Answer (score 18):

Fading to black is slightly more complicated than it has to be. The trick is to use the cross effect.

1. Add your video clip
2. Add a color strip (under *Effect Strip > Color*), the default is black, so leave it at that. Position the color strip at the end of the video clip.
3. Select your video strip then the color strip (Make sure to do it in that order. The cross effect will fade to whichever clip is selected last)
4. Add a cross effect
5. Play the animation.

Answer (score 11):

You can also animate the Transparency of the clip with a black color strip underneath:
[image]

(the transparency slider can be found in the *Video properties panel* (<kbd>N</kbd> in the Video Sequence Editor) under *Edit strip*.
[image]

Comment: Say if one moves the sequence horizontally on the timeline, is there a way to move the keyframes automatically?

Comment: @MikePan They do by default for me, they just don't refresh real time in the timeline.

Answer (score 5):

I usually keyframe the 'Multiply' value inside the 'Filter' panel (in N panel).

This way you don't need the color strip, so the VSE is less cluttered.

[image: MULTIPLY_strip]

Answer (score 2):

You can even just change the strip type to 'replace' and perform the transparency keyframe. Blender will mix to it's base color, black. As long as you don't render transparency out, you will get a fade to black.