# Why does a cross effect in the Video Sequence Editor overwrite a multiply effect?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a problem in the VSE.

I would like to have some nice dark corners in movie so I added a white image with black corners and then added a multiply effect.

It works, but when I add 'fade to black' to that by crossing video with black colour, just before the crossing my dark corners disappear. Multiply stops as cross begins.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your cross effect strip is being applied on top of the multiply effect strip.

The result of the effect strip completely overrides any strips below it. To work around this, use the cross effect strip to blend the multiply effect strip and the black color strip.

There are many variations on how to go about this, for example:

## Method 1

1. Add a Multiply effect strip with the image and the video strips selected.
2. Add a Cross effect strip with the Multiply effect strip and the color strip selected.

## Method 2

1. Add a Cross effect strip with the color strip and the video selected
2. Set the *Blend* of the image strip to *Multiply* in *Properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Edit strip > Blend*

## Method 3

1. Add a Multiply effect strip with the color strip and the video selected
2. Add a black color strip on top and keyframe the *Opacity* in *Properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Edit strip*

## Method 4

Without any effect strips:

1. Set the blend of the image to *Multiply* and move it above the video strip
2. Add a color strip on top and keyframe the *Opacity*.

Also see [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/fade-to-black-effect-in-video-sequence-editor?rq=1).