# How can I fade out separate images in the Blender VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am busy making an interview film. I already made .png images to use as footer labels. These footer labels contain the interviewees name. I want to fade the footer label out while the interviewee is talking. Is this possible?

Comment: You can animate the `Opacity` slider of the image strip to do that. Hover it with your mouse and hit 'I' on keyboard to add some keyframes... Then you can refine the animation in Graph Editor. Or, you can also use cross effect with black color strip like [described here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/fade-to-black-effect-in-video-sequence-editor/2104#2104).

Comment: If you speak French, there is a tutorial I made about titles in VSE [on Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/129268222).

Comment: Make sure that the Footer Label (referred to as a Lower third Super in video production) has an alpha channel, then make sure its properties have a blend type of Alpha Over.

Comment: The same way as Mikeycal Meyers is explaining the audio fade you can do an image Opacity fade: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1CjP2M7ZkE&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4&index=19